# proof of infinite Primes of the Form 4n-1

Tags: number-theory

would like help on the proof, I have most of it but got stuck in one part.
my proof is:
lets assume there are finite number of primes in the form 4n-1. let P be their product, define N=4P-1. so none of the primes of the form 4n-1 divide N yet there is a prime that divide N, say q.

I know I need to show that q is of the form 4n-1 but have no idea how to prove it, would greatly appreciate your help

Comment: The product of two primes of the form $4n+1$ is again of the form $4n+1,$ so it can't be the case that every prime dividing $4P-1$ is of the form $4n+1.$

Comment: How does it help me? sorry for the lack of knowledge but i'm just starting to learn number theory

Comment: Well, $P-1$ is divisible by an odd prime, and if not every prime dividing it is of the form $4n+1$ at least one must be of the form $4n-1$.

Comment: saulspatz, why must it be of the form 4n+1 or 4n-1? can't there be other forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose toward a contradiction that there is no prime of the form $4n-1$ that divides $N=4P-1$. Then every prime that divides $N=4P-1$ is of the form $4n+1$. But then the product of these primes is also of the form $4n+1$, contradicting the fact that their product is $N=4P-1$. Hence there exists a prime of the form $4n-1$ that divides $N=4P-1$.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't familiar that every prime must be of the form 4n+1 or 4n-1. why is it true?

Comment: @IdanDaniel Because every number is of the form $4n$, $4n+1$, $4n+2$ or $4n+3$.

Comment: ... and $4n$ or $4n+2$ can't be prime as they are divisible by $4$ and $2$ respectively.

Comment: ...except if they equal $2$.

Comment: so what about the form 4n+3? are we saying it can always be replaced by the form 4n-1?

Comment: @IdanDaniel I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: I mean every prime number of the form 4n+3 can be written as 4t-1?

Comment: Yes, exactly; take $t=n+1$.

Comment: Ok, sorry for I guess obvious questions. My professor never bothered to say every prime number must be of the two forms

Comment: @IdanDaniel and Servaes Please *search* before asking and answering FAQs. Rampant duplication is not good for the site.

Comment: @BillDubuque As similar as these questions are (as are a dozen others), OP's specific question about this proof is not adressed in the supposed duplicate questions. Though the answers in  the second question do seem helpful, at least.

Comment: @Servaes Your answer is a dupe of tens (if not hundres) of prior answers.

Comment: @BillDubuque Ok, I don't see it in the linked questions, but I also don't see a problem if it were.